# What's the difference between the docker commands: run, build, and create

Tags: docker

I see there are three `docker` commands that seem to do very similar things:

1. `docker build`
2. `docker create`
3. `docker run`

What are the differences between these commands?

Comment: [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/), [`docker create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/), [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)

Answer (score 115, accepted):

1. `docker build` [builds a new image from the source code](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/).
2. `docker create` [creates a writeable container from the image and prepares it for running](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/).
3. `docker run` [creates the container (same as `docker create`) and runs it](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/).

Answer (score 76):

1. `docker build .` converts your `Dockerfile` into an image.
2. `docker create your-image` creates a container from your image from step 1.
3. `docker start container_id` starts the container from step 2.
4. `docker run image` is a shortcut for 2. and 3. (`docker create image` and
   `docker start container_id`).

Here is the difference between `image` and `container`:

**Image**
An image is a specified snapshot of your filesystem and includes the starting command of your container. An image occupies just disk-space, it does not occupy memory/cpu. To create an image you usually create instructions how to build that image in a`Dockerfile`. `FROM` and `RUN` commands in the docker file create the file-snapshot. One may build an image from a docker file with `docker build <dockerfile>`

**Container**
You can create new containers with an image. Each container has a file-snapshot which is based on the file-snapshot created by the image. If you start a container it will run the command you specified in your docker file `CMD` and will use part of your memory and cpu. You can start or stop a container. If you create a container, its not started by default. This means you can't communicate to the container via ports etc. You have to start it first. One may create an container from an image by `docker create <image>`. When a container has been created it shows the id in the terminal. One may start it with `docker start <container_id>`.

Comment: So `docker create` shouldn't work when there is no image available or if `docker build` wasn't run before?

Comment: @winklerrr thats right because you need to specify an image id as a parameter of the docker create command.

Comment: Does `docker run` execute a `docker build` command automatically if there is no image available?

Comment: @winklerrr as far as I know - no

Comment: I hope it's not too wordy. But it's better to say "You can create new container(s) with an image." than "One image may have multiple containers.". Containers don't belong to images.